# The validation '[object Object]' isn't supported for the type 'String'

Tags: data-warehouse, jhipster

When I try to regenerate a model with jHipster, I get the following error:

> The validation '[object Object]' isn't supported for the type 'String'.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

The version of jHipster I am using is 3.6.1.

```
{

    /**
     * Hierarchy entity.
     * @author Shane Hayes.
     */
    entity HierarchyServiceCenter  {
        hrchyNode1IPId Integer required,
        hrchyNode1IPNm String maxlength(40),
        hrchyNode1Dsgntn String,
        hrchyNode2IPId Integer ,
        hrchyNode2IPNm String maxlength(40),
        hrchyNode2Dsgntn String,
        hrchyNode3IPId Integer ,
        hrchyNode3IPNm String maxlength(40),
        hrchyNode3Dsgntn String,
        hrchyLeafCode Integer required,
        hrchyLeafIPNm String maxlength(40) required,
        hrchyLeafDsgntn String ,
        hrchyLeafLctnGNm String,
        hrchySource String,
        hrchyTimeStampCreate ZonedDateTime required,
        hrchyTimeStampUpdate ZonedDateTime ,
    }
    /**
     * TimeDimention entity.
     * @author Shane Hayes.
     */
    entity TimeDimension {
        createDate ZonedDateTime required,
        updateDate ZonedDateTime
    }
    /**
     * MetricDimention entity.
     * @author Shane Hayes.
     */
    entity MetricDimension {
        metricDimKey String required max(10),
        metricName String max(35),
        asOfDate ZonedDateTime,
        metricFrequency String max(1),
        srcSystemID Integer,
        createTmStamp ZonedDateTime,
        updateTmStamp ZonedDateTime
    }
    /**
     * MetricTarget entity.
     * @author Shane Hayes.
     */
    entity MetricTarget {
        goalAmt BigDecimal required,
        autoComputed Integer,
        asOfDate ZonedDateTime required,
        goalEffDate ZonedDateTime required,
        endDate ZonedDateTime required,
        srcSystemID Integer,
        createDate ZonedDateTime,
        updateDate ZonedDateTime
    }
    relationship ManyToOne {
        MetricTarget{metricDimension} to MetricDimension,
        MetricTarget{hierarchyLeafCode} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyLeafCode},
        MetricTarget{hierarchyNode1IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode1IPId},
        MetricTarget{hierarchyNode2IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode2IPId},
        MetricTarget{hierarchyNode3IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode3IPId},
        MetricTarget{hierarchyNode4IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode4IPId},
        MetricTarget{timeDimensionId} to TimeDimension
    }
    entity MetricActual {
        actualAmt BigDecimal required,
        autoComputed Integer,
        asOfDate ZonedDateTime required,
        goalEffDate ZonedDateTime required,
        endDate ZonedDateTime required,
        srcSystemID Integer,
        createDate ZonedDateTime,
        updateDate ZonedDateTime
    }
    relationship ManyToOne {
        MetricActual{metricDimension} to MetricDimension,
        MetricActual{hierarchyLeafCode} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyLeafCode},
        MetricActual{hierarchyNode1IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode1IPId},
        MetricActual{hierarchyNode2IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode2IPId},
        MetricActual{hierarchyNode3IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode3IPId},
        MetricActual{hierarchyNode4IPId} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyNode4IPId},
        MetricActual{timeDimensionId} to TimeDimension
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the first error are the curly braces at the beginning and at the end of the JDL.
- The second error are the `max(35)` elements. You should write instead `maxlength(35)`.
- The third error are the Relationships between MetricTarget and MetricDimension and between MetricActual and MetricDimension. These are unidirectional Relationships (ManyToOne) so you should write e.g. `MetricTarget{hierarchyLeafCode} to HierarchyServiceCenter` instead of `MetricTarget{hierarchyLeafCode} to HierarchyServiceCenter{hrchyLeafCode}`.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the all encompassing curly braces.  They should not be there.  Second paste the whole thing into [JDL studio](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/) and make sure it passes the syntax check.  It will tell you at the top in red what line has an issue if any exist.